Rendering transparent UI in Linear Color Space
As you may know, Unity can have issues correctly rendering transparent 2D Sprites/Textures exported from Photoshop or Figma. Reason being that most of these tools operate in Gamma color space while Unity (can) use Linear color space.
There are a few workarounds, the one I find the most elegant is this one by Ming Wai Chan. She adds an extra UI camera and translates the UI to Gamma space. https://cmwdexint.com/2019/05/30/3d-scene-need-linear-but-ui-need-gamma/
Sadly the solution is a few years old and I couldn't get it to work in Unity 2022.3 and URP 14.
Maybe you guys have some Feedback or another, maybe better, approach for the Linear Color Space Texture issue. Appreciate y’all.
====
P.S. It is rendered correctly when I switch to Gamma Color Space in Unity but for our project at least, that’s not an option.
UPDATE:
Still not solved. Tried the second camera approach in a new, empty project but to no avail. Could be a user error though because I had to adjust some parts of the Render Feature script because it was deprecated. Here's the current state: https://pastebin.com/qYkBCFkB
Changed Color Profiles in Figma to Display P3, no change.
Found a setting on the Unity Canvas component called "VertexColorAlwaysInGamma". Sound promising, right? No change.
And tried all import settings of the texture, even tried setting all pixels to linear in a PostProcessor script.
The only thing I can say for sure is that (linear) Unity renders the Texture differently than Figma and Photoshop. Loading the file into Photoshop looks right. Here's a comparison between Unity and Figma:

And a link to the above source file if somebody wants to try it first-hand: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gBgTbAEOMVT01K9T6DXs-v5NRgTQswKu/view?usp=sharing
UPDATE2:
What i considered a Unity-exclusive issue, is actually not. Gimp renders the image the same as Unity does! Don't know how that helps but it sure should :D

UPDATE3:
Based on this answer I tried a custom shader which corrects the gamma of the texture manually. The results are not as desired but it might be interesting that using that kind of color correction has almost the same effect as turning off sRGB?


Alright, I sort of lost an entire afternoon to this, but I believe I've got it nailed down now.

The problem comes down to the fact that doing arithmetic on colors is a finicky thing, because the result entirely depends on the color space being used. In this case, interpolating (blending, with the alpha) between two colors in gamma space will produce a perceptually different color than blending in linear space, even if both colors being interpolated are perceptually identical.
So, the color that photoshop outputs is the result of interpolating in gamma space. To get the same color in Unity, you need to get everything into gamma space and have the interpolation take place there.
That's why moving the texture to linear color was not working correctly: both the scene render and the texture were in the same color space, sure, but not in the correct one!
So, the solution is to take four steps:

Render everything except UI normally.
Blit this image into gamma space.
Render the UI without applying gamma correction.
Blit the result into linear space so things look normal.

The first step just requires removing the UI layer from the cullingMask of the camera, and Unity handles the rest.
The meat and potatoes of the process, then, is a render feature that creates three passes for the remaining steps:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class GammaUIFix : ScriptableRendererFeature
{
    // We are not allowed to access the camera target from rendererFeature, only inside the pass
    // so, in order to tell the pass to use the camera color target as source/target, we can use this enum
    public enum RTHandleType { Custom, CameraColor }

    [SerializeField] LayerMask layerMask;
    [SerializeField] Material toGammaMat;
    [SerializeField] Material toLinearMat;
    RTHandle intermediateRT;
    RTHandle customDepthAndStencil;

    public GammaUIFix()
    { }

    public override void Create()
    {
    }

    public override void AddRenderPasses(ScriptableRenderer renderer, ref RenderingData renderingData)
    {
        if (renderingData.cameraData.cameraType != CameraType.Game)
            return;
            
        RenderTextureDescriptor colorDescriptor = new(Screen.width, Screen.height, RenderTextureFormat.Default, 0);
        RenderingUtils.ReAllocateIfNeeded(ref intermediateRT, colorDescriptor, name: "intermediate");
        RenderTextureDescriptor depthDescriptor = new(Screen.width, Screen.height, RenderTextureFormat.Depth, 32);
        RenderingUtils.ReAllocateIfNeeded(ref customDepthAndStencil, depthDescriptor, name: "customDepth");

        BlitPass toGamma = new(new BlitPass.Settings()
        {
            renderPassEvent = RenderPassEvent.AfterRenderingTransparents,
            material = toGammaMat,
            sourceType = RTHandleType.CameraColor,

            targetType = RTHandleType.Custom,
            target = intermediateRT
        });

        DrawRenderersPass drawUI = new(new DrawRenderersPass.Settings()
        {
            renderPassEvent = RenderPassEvent.AfterRenderingTransparents,
            layerMask = layerMask,
            target = intermediateRT,
            depthAndStencil = customDepthAndStencil
        });

        BlitPass toLinear = new(new BlitPass.Settings()
        {
            renderPassEvent = RenderPassEvent.AfterRenderingTransparents,
            material = toLinearMat,

            sourceType = RTHandleType.Custom,
            source = intermediateRT,

            targetType = RTHandleType.CameraColor
        });

        renderer.EnqueuePass(toGamma);
        renderer.EnqueuePass(drawUI);
        renderer.EnqueuePass(toLinear);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        intermediateRT?.Release();
        customDepthAndStencil?.Release();
    }

    //Draws all renderers of a specific layer into target RTHandle, even if that layer is culled by the camera
    class DrawRenderersPass : ScriptableRenderPass
    {
        Settings settings;
        List<ShaderTagId> forwardOnlyShaderTagIds = new()
        {
            new ShaderTagId("SRPDefaultUnlit"),
            new ShaderTagId("UniversalForward"),
            new ShaderTagId("UniversalForwardOnly"), // Legacy shaders (do not have a gbuffer pass) are considered forward-only for backward compatibility
        };


        public DrawRenderersPass(Settings _settings)
        {
            this.settings = _settings;
            renderPassEvent = _settings.renderPassEvent;
        }

        public override void OnCameraSetup(CommandBuffer cmd, ref RenderingData renderingData)
        {
            ConfigureTarget(settings.target, settings.depthAndStencil);
        }

        public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData)
        {
            CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get("Draw Renderers Pass");

            DrawingSettings drawingSettings = CreateDrawingSettings(forwardOnlyShaderTagIds, ref renderingData, SortingCriteria.CommonTransparent);
            FilteringSettings filteringSettings = new(RenderQueueRange.all, settings.layerMask);
            RenderStateBlock renderStateBlock = new(RenderStateMask.Nothing);

            renderingData.cameraData.camera.TryGetCullingParameters(out ScriptableCullingParameters cullingParameters);
            cullingParameters.cullingMask = (uint)(int)settings.layerMask;
            context.DrawRenderers(
                context.Cull(ref cullingParameters),
                ref drawingSettings,
                ref filteringSettings,
                ref renderStateBlock);


            context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
            cmd.Clear();
            CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
        }

        [System.Serializable]
        public class Settings
        {
            public RenderPassEvent renderPassEvent;
            public RTHandle target;
            public RTHandle depthAndStencil;
            public LayerMask layerMask;
        }
    }

    //blits from source to target using the provided material
    class BlitPass : ScriptableRenderPass
    {
        Settings settings;


        public BlitPass(Settings _settings)
        {
            this.settings = _settings;
            renderPassEvent = _settings.renderPassEvent;
        }

        public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData)
        {
            CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get("Blit Pass");
            RTHandle source;
            if (settings.sourceType == RTHandleType.CameraColor)
                source = renderingData.cameraData.renderer.cameraColorTargetHandle;
            else
                source = settings.source;

            RTHandle target;
            if (settings.targetType == RTHandleType.CameraColor)
                target = renderingData.cameraData.renderer.cameraColorTargetHandle;
            else
                target = settings.target;

            //This seems to happen when selecting certain objects in the inspector? I have no idea, man
            if (source.rt == null || target.rt == null)
                return;

            if (source == target)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Cannot blit from source to itself! Use an intermediate target");
                return;
            }

            Blitter.BlitCameraTexture(cmd, source, target, settings.material, 0);
            context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
            cmd.Clear();
            CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
        }

        [System.Serializable]
        public class Settings
        {
            public RenderPassEvent renderPassEvent;
            public Material material;

            public RTHandleType sourceType;
            public RTHandle source;

            public RTHandleType targetType;
            public RTHandle target;
        }
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
}

I'm not going to give a blow by blow, because I don't think the code itself is very mysterious. There are some slightly confusing details in how you need to interact with the API, I guess, but the general idea should be clear.
You will also need two shaders for the gamma there-and-back-again:
ToGamma
Shader "CustomEffects/ToGamma"
{
    HLSLINCLUDE
    
        #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"
        // The Blit.hlsl file provides the vertex shader (Vert),
        // the input structure (Attributes), and the output structure (Varyings)
        #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core/Runtime/Utilities/Blit.hlsl"
        #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core/ShaderLibrary/Color.hlsl"

        float4 ToGamma (Varyings input) : SV_Target
        {
            float3 color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_BlitTexture, sampler_LinearClamp, input.texcoord).rgb;
            return float4(LinearToSRGB(color), 1);
        }

    ENDHLSL
    
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline"}
        LOD 100
        ZTest Always ZWrite Off Cull Off
        Pass
        {
            Name "ToGamma"

            HLSLPROGRAM
            
            #pragma vertex Vert
            #pragma fragment ToGamma
            
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}

ToLinear
Shader "CustomEffects/ToLinear"
{
    HLSLINCLUDE
    
        #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"
        // The Blit.hlsl file provides the vertex shader (Vert),
        // the input structure (Attributes), and the output structure (Varyings)
        #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core/Runtime/Utilities/Blit.hlsl"
        #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core/ShaderLibrary/Color.hlsl"

        float4 ToLinear (Varyings input) : SV_Target
        {
            float3 color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_BlitTexture, sampler_LinearClamp, input.texcoord).rgb;
            return float4(SRGBToLinear(color), 1);
        }
    
    ENDHLSL
    
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline"}
        LOD 100
        ZTest Always ZWrite Off Cull Off
        Pass
        {
            Name "ToLinear"

            HLSLPROGRAM
            
            #pragma vertex Vert
            #pragma fragment ToLinear
            
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}

Once you have all that, you just set up the render feature and you are done!

Although I should mention at one point I got a mysterious persistent error about the RTHandle being null that then disappeared upon restarting the editor. I don't know what that was about, and cannot guarantee it won't happen again :(
EDIT (again): Fixed the pesky RTHandle errors and got masks to work by adding a custom depth/stencil buffer to the DrawRenderers pass.

Nice, that's definitely going in the right direction! Here's the side-by-side of how it looks compared to Gamma: image. Unity also provides a method col.a = LinearToGammaSpace(col.a); to more or less achieve the same result. It's still an approximation but it's close. Just the glow / drop shadow is much stronger and produces artifacts. If this is fixable that would be great. If it's just not, I don't mind exporting these by themselves. But let's see. Thanks!

Have a look at the edit I just did, I think it might be solved!

You frickin legend! Thanks so much for spending the time, it's really really appreciated. For anyone using this solution, don't forget to disable sRGB on the Texture.
While the colors look as in the original, I have two more issues. I'll try to solve those myself but just if you find another minute:


Every time I click on a GameObject containing an Image component in the hierarchy, these two errors are spammed. Maybe the same one you got?
Error 1
Error 2


Masks no longer work in the UI.


Thanks again! :)

No problem! Yeah, those are the errors. It seems to be a problem with the RTHandle allocation...? I don't really have a lot of experience with this, so I'm not sure. As for the masks, that must be something with the stencil buffer not being used. Not really sure how to fix that either, but maybe searching for that specifically (stencil effects in custom passes) will lead to something.

I made another edit to the answer with those last changes (commenting because I believe you don't get notified of the edits)

Yess, that's it - works like a charm. Thanks again!

You could try importing your texture into Unity without an alpha channel and applying it to your background. Then, adjust the alpha channel of your background color to match Figma.

Otherwise, disabling "sRGB (Color Texture)" in your import settings seems to provide a good result.



Thanks for the answer but both ideas do not help.
1: Removing alpha from the image and managing it in Unity is not that trivial. Every image would need to be split into non transparent and transparent parts. Alpha Gradients (the glow / shadow) can't be replicated and every non-rectangular form would need a mask. If I understood you correctly.
2: Your image looks like how it's rendered in my engine. And sadly that's the issue, it's way too desaturated.
But thanks!
